# The requested URL /REST/WebService/MyMethod was not found on this server

Tags: java, web-services, rest

i'm new to REST Service. i've done a small REST Webservice application and deployed in my online tomcat webserver,

My link -->
**http://sample.com.au/REST/WebService/MyMethod?name=sss**

but i'm getting the following message

**The requested URL /REST/WebService/MyMethod was not found on this server.**

when i run the similar in eclipse locally its working....

can anyone please tell me some solution for this...

my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd'>

<web-app>
:
:
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/REST/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My **FeedService.java**

```
package webService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import model.ProjectManager;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import dto.FeedObjects;

@Path("/WebService")
public class FeedService {
    
    
    
    @GET
    @Path("/MyMethod")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String names(@QueryParam("name") String name)
    {
        System.out.println("name----------->"+name);
        String feeds = null;
        try
        {
        ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = null;
        ProjectManager projectManager= new ProjectManager();
        feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds(name);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(feedData));
        feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println("Exception Error"); //Console 
        }
        return feeds;
    }

    
}
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/iloadlogistics.com.au"/>
```

Comment: Your Deplyoment descriptor is wrong.

Comment: whats' the wrong in that sir...its working in eclipse.....

Comment: Oh ok. I got that there is a problem in the context then. In which server are you deploying the project?

Comment: apache tomcat.....even after deployment ....i've restarted the server....but still getting the same exception

Comment: @karthick sir can u please tell me wats the problem.........

Comment: Normally when you run in eclipse your context will be pointing to your project name. But when you deploy in tomcat you have to make sure that the same context is preserved or else it will throw an error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38769/discussion-between-karthick-and-user2040500)

Comment: still not working.....

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html).  Specifically check Example 4.1 and Example 4.5.  Should you not deploy that way?

Comment: If your problem is solved kindly update the question how you solved.  It will be helpful for others.

Comment: no sir....the problem is not yet solved......i'm checking with the server right now

Comment: I have done my deployment similar to Example 4.1 and Example 4.5.  Did you try that way?  It worked for me.